# Поиск на сайте только по заданным ID

Tags: php

Как доработать поиск на сайте только по заранее прописанным ID категории ?
Сейчас мой поиск выводит все похожие слова из базы , а я хочу что бы он выводил только с определённой таблице по ID.
**Вот мой поиск**:

```
<form role="search" style="width:17em; margin: 0.6em 1em;">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск товара" name="keyword">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="height:3.5em;width:1em; background: rgb(168, 2, 0);">
            <span style="color:white;margin-top: -0.3em;margin-left: -10px;" class="fa fa-search fa-2x" style="color:white;"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Запрос сейчас таков**

```
}else{
        $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
                FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND Menu_name LIKE ? 
                ORDER BY m.Menu_ID ASC LIMIT ?, ?";
    }
```

**Что то вроде этого хочу получить** :

```
    "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
                FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND c.Category_ID IN (72,73,74,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,35,85,86)  
                ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
```

Comment: Каким образом он у вас вообще ищет на данный момент?

Comment: @InDevX - Как я понимаю он ищет по ключевому слову вроде вот так  `if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){ 
   // проверить значение ключевой переменной
   $keyword = $function->sanitize($_GET['keyword']);
   $bind_keyword = "%".$keyword."%";
  }else{
   $keyword = "";
   $bind_keyword = $keyword;
  }`

Comment: Я имел ввиду, запрос покажите ()добавьте в вопос какой сейчас есть

Comment: @InDevX - Как я думаю запрос для поиска вот такой  `}else{
   $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
     FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
     WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND Menu_name LIKE ? 
     ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC";
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот такое решение мне подошло**

```
    WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND c.Category_ID IN (72,73,74,77,78,79,80,81) AND Menu_name LIKE ?
```

**или исключить из поиска**

```
WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND c.Category_ID NOT IN (50) AND Menu_name LIKE ?
```